# MySQL Alter Full Text Search Columns

Tags: mysql

Ok, so I've full text index on one table for **col1** and **col2** for example. I want to change this to only have **col1** included in the full text index. How to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, identify the name of your Full Text Index using the following MySQL query;

```
SHOW CREATE TABLE your_table_name;
```

Then run the following MySQL query to drop the table;

```
ALTER TABLE your_table_name DROP INDEX name_of_index_identified_by_previous_query_above;
```

Then create your Full Text Index again using the following code;

```
ALTER TABLE your_table_name ADD FULLTEXT INDEX `FullText` ('col1', 'col2', 'col3', 'etc');
```

Answer (score 2):

You can not ALTER INDEX in MySQL, you need to [`DROP INDEX`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/drop-index.html) and [`CREATE INDEX`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-index.html) a new one